# R: function cut

Tags: r, break, cut

Here is my data:

```
>my.cut <- cut(my.variable, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.5, -0.25, -0.1, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.5, 1, Inf), right = FALSE)

>levels(my.cut)
    "[-Inf,-0.5)"  "[-0.5,-0.25)"  "[-0.25,-0.1)"  "[-0.1,0)"  "[0,0.02)"  "[0.02,0.05)"  "[0.05,0.15)"  "[0.15,0.3)"  "[0.3,0.5)"  "[0.5,1)"  "[1, Inf)"
```

Expected result:

```
>levels(my.cut)
    "[-Inf,-0.5)"  "[-0.5,-0.25)" "[-0.25,-0.1)" "[-0.1,0)"  "0"  "(0,0.02)" "[0.02,0.05)"  "[0.05,0.15)"  "[0.15,0.3)"  "[0.3,0.5)"   "[0.5,1)"      "[1, Inf)"
```

In the expected result, there is single figure `0` which I only want to choose the `my.variable==0`, but with the formula of the `my.cut`, there is no single 0 cause `breaks` can only be used for interval. So how could I do?

Hope to get your answer soon! Thanks!

Comment: `levels(my.cut)[1] <- "0"`

Comment: @scoa Sorry I don't think that you have understood my question :( The original `levels(my.cut)` is  `"[-Inf,-0.5)"  "[-0.5,-0.25)" "[-0.25,-0.1)" "[-0.1,0)"    "[0,0.02)" "[0.02,0.05)"  "[0.05,0.15)"  "[0.15,0.3)"  "[0.3,0.5)"   "[0.5,1)"      "[1, Inf)"` which there is no single 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly put each value into a group. This is more flexible, but also a lot more verbose.

One way of doing this could be to define a bespoke cut function and then apply it to every element of your vector.

```
my.variable <- rnorm(100)

bespoke_cut <- function(value){

  if (value < 0.1) return('[-Inf, 0.1)')

  if (value < 0)   return('[0.1, 0)')

  if (value == 0)  return('0')

  return('(0, Inf]')
}

my.cut <- sapply(my.variable, bespoke_cut)

my.cut <- factor(my.cut)
```

I've only done a few of the groupings you wanted, but I think it should be apparent how to add extra groups.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can hope for with 'cut' is to specify a really small range for 0, i.e.,

```
cps = c(-Inf, -0.1, 0-.Machine$double.eps, 0+.Machine$double.eps, 0.02, Inf)
bgroup = cut(c(-10, 10, 0,0), breaks = cps)
cat(deparse(levels(bgroup)), "\n") ## use this to edit the levels more easily
levels(bgroup) = c("(-Inf, -0.1]", "(-0.1,0)", "0", "(0,0.02]", "(0.02, Inf]")
table(bgroup)
```

Obviously, the display levels are not identical to those used to cut the data, but if you are okay with that window around 0, then the solution is to form the cuts with that value then change the labels.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this : cut, assign 0 where `my.variable == 0`, refactor.

```
my.variable <- rnorm(100)
my.variable[sample(1:100,2)] <- 0
my.cut <- cut(my.variable, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.5, -0.25, -0.1, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.5, 1, Inf), right = FALSE)
lvl <- levels(my.cut)
lvlR <- c(lvl[1:4],"0","(0,0.02)",lvl[6:11])
my.cut <- as.character(my.cut)
my.cut[my.variable == 0] <- 0
my.cut <- factor(my.cut,levels=lvlR)
rm(lvl,lvlR)
```